# ActiveRecord modify parameters on initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for is proper usage of virtual attributes?

Regardless.

Here is an overview of my ActiveRecord in-so-far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, email: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And the schema associated:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |u|
      u.string :email
      u.string :username
      u.string :password_hash
      u.string :salt
      u.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My goal is to be able to initialize a new record with (something like) the following:

```
User.new({"email"=>"emailaddresshere",
          "username"=>"usernamehere",
          "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
          "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"})
```

I need a way to, after all the lovely validation checks, but before attempting to create a new DB record, transform the password into the password_hash, as well as generate a salt.
I know HOW to acquire the hash and salt, I just don't know how I would be able to interject a snippet of code into the record creation process, to modify the parameters provided.  I am also unsure of how to make sure that it all works without throwing an UnknownAttributeError.

Any way to do this? I could obviously write a "def register" method which manually transforms everything into a new record, but then it would render the password and password_confirmation validations useless, as the record will have been transformed by the time it hits User.new().

Comment: I think my question also stems from a severe lack of overall understanding of the ActiveRecord processes... and somewhat of ruby in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Activerecord Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

In your case you could use `after_validation` or `before_save` callback.

An example would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, email: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  before_save :salt_new_password, :if=>:self.password_changed?

  private
  def salt_new_password
    # self.password = <whatever logic you use>
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I'm going to rename the `password_hash` field to just `password`, but until I do that, I'm getting an unknown attribute error on `password`.  I know it's a bit off-topic of the original question, but is there a way to explicitly just say not to store it in the DB?

Comment: Also, thank you for the reference material, that certainly clears things up for me a bit!

Comment: Ah, found it. `attr_accessor` is apparently what I was looking for.  I had seen it earlier but the reference that described it did a poor job.  New source: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-data-models-with-rails--net-20205